# Understanding Prometheus memory usage spikes

Tags: prometheus

My Prometheus instance has intermittent memory spikes which double its RSS size. This causes it to hit the container limits configured in k8s and OOM the instance.

It generally sits in the ~65GB region, which is bang on what the very useful calculator [here](https://www.robustperception.io/how-much-ram-does-prometheus-2-x-need-for-cardinality-and-ingestion). The container is configured for a 120GB memory limit.

I can see that the spikes in process_resident_memory_bytes are matched by increases in `go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes` and the recovery (when it recovers and doesn't OOM) results in an an increase in `go_memstats_heap_released_bytes` as memory is freed and an increase in go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes. So it's garbage collecting, but I'm trying to find the trigger for this so I can mitigate it.

You can see what my benchmarks look like [here](https://snapshot.raintank.io/dashboard/snapshot/Qf0gdpXTScgoawBDnfgbVvnXTMePR8rU?orgId=2) (link valid until 20190902) :

Any ideas or insight appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say what is actually happening, but the most common issue I've run into is queries. In particular, if you take an otherwise harmless Grafana dashboard and change its time range to the past `1y`, you've suddenly brought everything to a halt. It used to be that this would kill Prometheus with OOM. It is now somewhat better behaved, with hard limits on the number of samples every query will load before it gets canceled, but it's still easy to double memory usage by running arbitrary queries against it. This is why I'm toying with the idea of running 2 instances, not for general availability reasons, but just so one never gets hit with user queries and can be relied on for alerting.

That being said, your best bet is to go to `http://your.prometheus.server:9090/debug/pprof` and make use of the great choice of profiling data available there. Ideally in conjunction with something like `go pprof`. In particular, this command line may be of use while a memory spike is in progress (when compared to one obtained at rest):

```
go pprof http://your.prometheus.server:9090/debug/pprof/heap
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read and answer! I'm already running a concurrent query limit of 10, with the default sample limit per query of 50m, but I don't see active queries correlating with the time of the spike.

Like you, I'm on the path to segregating ingestion / alerting from dashboard queries, but there are issues there too in scaling. A recent blog of Brian's suggests that alternative solutions would be better for scaling than a secondary prometheus : https://www.robustperception.io/putting-queues-in-front-of-prometheus-for-reliability

Comment: The heap dump looks like it could provide some insight - I'll grab that next time we see a spike.

Comment: I now have a go tool pprof capture of the heap at the time of a spike. I'll try and get the svg hosted to share.

Comment: That's about 1/3 ingestion, 1/3 remote write, 1/5 active queries from HTTP API (likely high cardinality as it's in `ExpandPostings`), and the rest is TSDB. Based on the graphs, I think someone sent a heavy query_range query at you in a way that the memory accounting doesn't quite cover. I'd be interested to know what that query's selectors look like.

Comment: I'm trying to track that down - at first look I thought it was label_values() queries without metric names in users' grafana dashboard variables. There were many launches of the same dashboard that had those queries around the time the spike kicked off. I'm going to fix any occurrences of those first and then check again.

Comment: @brian-brazil At the moment, I suspect it's pattern matching against label_values e.g.  

/api/v1/series?match[]=req_count&start=1566977901&end=1566981501  
coming from a variable population query like :  

label_values(req_count{host_name=~"$Hostname",app_name=~"$App_name"},pid)  

They'd have been worse before I changed them yesterday when they would have looked like :
  
label_values({host_name=~"$Hostname",app_name=~"$App_name"},pid)

Comment: FYI, with the latest Prometheus release ([2.12.0](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/tag/v2.12.0)) you should be able to see all the queries currently in flight in some log file. (Haven't tried it, so I don't know which file. Here's [the pull request](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/5794).) You could check that too the next time you see a spike.

Comment: The `series` endpoint won't hit `populateSeries`, it's an actual query doing that. The file is `queries.active` in the data directory.

Comment: Thanks @AlinSînpălean - I'd wanted to understand the root cause before upgrading, but 2.12 (currently 2.9.2) is my intention in the near future.

Comment: Thanks @brian-brazil - I've got the queries from the apache logs so I will try each of those to find the culprit